# Show equation equivalent in RG of 1d Ising Model

Tags: renormalization, ising-model

I know the Ising model is given by

$$Z= \sum_{\sigma_i=\pm 1} e^{-F + J \sum_i \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} - h\sum_i \sigma_i}$$

and that if h=0I can sum over even spins and get the partition function which looks the same except that the new coupling x' obeys the equation:

$$e^{x'}= \sqrt{cosh(2x)}  $$

I have been trying to rewrite this last equation as :

$$tanh(x') = tanh^2(x)$$
but I don't seem to be able to.

---

I attempted starting by :

$cosh(2x) = \frac{e^2x +1}{2e^x} $ so $\frac{e^2x +1}{e^x}=2e^{2x'}$ I thought of inverting this last eqaution but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$e^{x'} = \sqrt{\cosh(2x)}$$ then
$$e^{2x'} = \cosh(2x).$$
But then $$e^{2x'} = \cosh(2x) = \frac{1+\tanh^2x}{1-\tanh^2x}$$
so
$$e^{2x'} - 1 = \frac{2\tanh^2x}{1-\tanh^2x}$$
and
$$e^{2x'} + 1 = \frac{2}{1-\tanh^2x}.$$
Finally
$$\tanh x' = \frac{e^{2x'} - 1}{e^{2x'} + 1} = \tanh^2 x$$

Comment: Thank you so much, somehow I didn't find/know the relation equation between $cosh(2x)$ and $tanh^2(x)$.